cannot make bootable ubuntu install on usb drive on windows
when I try to do it with Balena etcher this error comes up
Something went wrong while opening
C:\Users\gotsa\Downloads\ubuntu-24.04.1desktop-amd64(2).iso.
Error:(0, h.requestMetadata) is not a function
I don't know where to go from here

use Rufus, Ventoy, YUMI,  UNetbootin, or boot with the iso file from Windows without USB  like this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1524288/1698042

This question is similar to: What is the proper way of creating installation media from Ubuntu iso?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
